# how to pass Error Handlers- Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, rpa

I am working on a Robocorp project (robot framework not in python).
It's a Windows application, Once I sign in a warning dialog pops up saying “You are already signed in, do you wish to continue?”
**H**ow can I introduce this to my code that if it appears I click yes else continue the rest of the code.

Thanks

Is there any library that helps me add conditions if the pop up image appears click yes
else continue the code
or if the dialog id appears